# Como pegar um dado do tipo char pelo JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, char, joptionpane

```
char cadastrar;
cadastrar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("cadastrar: A-aluno P-professor M-medico");
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso:

```
String resposta = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("cadastrar: A-aluno P-professor M-medico");
if (resposta == null) {
    // O usuário clicou no botão Cancelar ou no X do canto da tela.
} else if (resposta.length() != 1) {
    // Resposta inválida. Tratar esse caso aqui.
} else {
    char cadastrar = resposta.charAt(0);
    // Continuar com o código aqui ...
}
```

Eis o que aparece:

[image: JOptionPane.showInputDialog]

Porém, se você está dando uma lista com três opções para o usuário escolher uma e já está usando `JOptionPane` para isso, faz mais sentido pedir para o usuário escolher o botão com a opção que ele quer ao invés de pedir para ele digitar uma letra:

```
String[] opcoes = { "Aluno", "Professor", "Médico" };
int escolha = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
    null,
    "Escolha qual você quer cadastrar",
    "O que você quer cadastrar?",
    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    null,
    opcoes,
    opcoes[0]);

if (escolha == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
    // Usuário clicou no X do canto da tela.
} else {
    char cadastrar = opcoes[escolha].charAt(0);
    // Continuar com o código aqui ...
}
```

Eis o que aparece:

[image: JOptionPane.showInputDialog]

Você não consegue obter um `char` diretamente do `JOptionPane` porque o método `showInputDialog` pede ao usuário para digitar uma linha de texto, e portanto há vários caracteres ao invés de um só. Já o método `showOptionDialog` retorna um `int` que corresponde ao índice do botão que foi escolhido. O `CLOSED_OPTION` corresponde ao caso onde o usuário clica no [image: X] no canto da janelinha que aparece.

No mais, não é boa ideia usar um `char` para representar um conjunto com os valores aluno, professor e médico. Isso é algo que vai totalmente contra os princípios de programação orientada a objetos que é o que você está aprendendo. Esse tipo de coisa seria melhor representada por alguma classe ou por um `enum`. No entanto, sem olhar para o contexto no qual você quer usar isso, não dá para apontar ao certo qual seria a melhor alternativa.

Comment: não dá para pegar um dado char pelo JOpotionPane ?

Comment: @brennoamaral Resposta editada.